# Cause for/of in sentence

Tags: prepositions, collocations

If one wants to say:

> The **cause of/for** his interest in ... was ...

should one use **of** or **for** in this context
As far as I understand from the previous research, it should be for as it is an outcome.

Comment: [Google's Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cause+%2A+his+interest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cause%20of%20his%20interest%3B%2Cc0) suggests the only word that can go there is "of".

Comment: Please add parentheses or put in **bold** the words you want to highlight.

Answer (score 0):

The **cause of** his interest...

**cause of** something

but **reason for** something

reason for success.